# How to save youtube video url details like title,description,thumbnail,videoid in to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, youtube

Hi Friends am trying to save the details like title,description,thumbnail,videoid in to mysql using php is there any reference . I need to save them into my database once the video url is submitted..

Thanks

Comment: There is a term called scrapping.. You need to learn that

Comment: ok is there any references in github please

Comment: Google `Scrapping with php`

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started you can use the API. or simply visit your youtube url using PHP CURL and parse the result. PHP CURL will give you the page where you need to extract all information using PHP String Functions. See scraping, string functions etc

Answer (score 4):

You can get the data from this API

https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID&format=json

Comment: nice yeah works fine,

Answer (score 0):

From the url grab the id, i.e. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJJT0HLKtzA&list=PL10A80E048A9E16BA&index=11` the id here is `DJJT0HLKtzA` you can easily get that using $_GET.

Secondly you need to use youtube's api to get the data you're after using that id. Read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/#php)

Or what's even easier and quicker is using youtube's oEmbed (know more about oEmbed [here](http://oembed.com/)), i.e. `https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJJT0HLKtzA&format=json` that's using the same id in the previous example returns JSON data:

```
{
   "version":"1.0",
   "thumbnail_url":"https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/DJJT0HLKtzA\/hqdefault.jpg",
   "width":459,
   "author_url":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/user\/ThatVideoMakingKid",
   "provider_name":"YouTube",
   "type":"video",
   "provider_url":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/",
   "title":"Evanescence-Whisper Lyrics (Fallen)",
   "thumbnail_height":360,
   "thumbnail_width":480,
   "height":344,
   "author_name":"ThatVideoMakingKid",
   "html":"\u003ciframe width=\"459\" height=\"344\" src=\"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/DJJT0HLKtzA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen\u003e\u003c\/iframe\u003e"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what you've asked this would be the easiest way:

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXnqkVTFUqY&format=json"));
$author = $request->author_url;
```

or

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXnqkVTFUqY&format=json"), true);
$author = $request['author_url'];
```

Then I believe you know how to add values into your database.

Here a reminder of what data you can get:

- provider_name
- thumbnail_width
- thumbnail_height
- title
- html
- type
- provider_url
- height
- author_url
- thumbnail_url
- author_name
- version

Hope this is what you were asking for.